# How to use Tree View control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Can anybody help me of using `tree_view` control in `asp.net` ? I want to use this control without using database. Can anybody give me a sample of how to use it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4fz6xk2(v=vs.80).aspx